# Ooyala Player Event - Notification when player reaches a certain point of the video

Tags: javascript, api, ooyala

I have taken a deep look at the Ooyala Player JS API, searching for an event that would be triggered when the current video that is being played at the moment reached to, let's say, 75% of its length.

Ooyala provides a way to consult how many 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% views a certain video had, but I couldn't find a way to do what I want.

I've checked everything at http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/concepts/book_api_player.html

Has anyone been through this before?
Do you know any aother source of information that could help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
var videoPlayer = OO.Player.create('Player', embedcode, {
    autoplay: true,
    onCreate: function (player) {
        mesb = player.mb;
    }    
});

mesb.subscribe(OO.EVENTS.PLAYBACK_READY, 'example', _.bind(this.videoPlaying, this));
mesb.subscribe(OO.EVENTS.PLAYHEAD_TIME_CHANGED, 'example', _.bind(this.playheadTime, this));
function videoPlaying() {
    var title, desc, embed, dur;
    var vData = videoPlayer.getItem();
    dur = vData.time;

}

function playheadTime() {
    phPos = videoPlayer.getPlayheadTime();
    if (phPos > 90) {
        alert('you are 90 seconds in to the video!');
    }
```

**dur** will give you the total time of video.
**phPos** will give you the current playhead time.

You should be able to do the math and have the video trigger an action once a certain percentage is reached. In my example, I have an alert set to go off when the video reached 90 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
I think this will work
var videoPlayer = OO.Player.create('Player', embedcode, {
    autoplay: true,
    onCreate: function (player) {
        mesb = player.mb;
    }    
});

mesb.subscribe(OO.EVENTS.PLAYBACK_READY, 'example', _.bind(this.videoPlaying, this));
mesb.subscribe(OO.EVENTS.PLAYHEAD_TIME_CHANGED, 'example', _.bind(this.playheadTime, this));
function videoPlaying() {
    var title, desc, embed, dur;
    var vData = videoPlayer.getItem();
    dur = vData.time;

}

function playheadTime() {
    if((videoPlayer.getPlayheadTime())>= (videoPlayer.getDuration()*0.25)){ 
      alert('play 25%') 
    }
    if((videoPlayer.getPlayheadTime())>= (videoPlayer.getDuration()*0.50)){ 
      alert('play 50%') 
    }
    if((videoPlayer.getPlayheadTime())>= (videoPlayer.getDuration()*0.75)){ 
      alert('play 75%') 
    }
    if((videoPlayer.getPlayheadTime())>= (videoPlayer.getDuration()*1.00)){ 
      alert('play 100%') 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code provided in the earlier answers helped me, but needed some modification. Needed to wrap it in `OO.ready`, and and make modification so that the code is called exactly 4 times: on completing 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100%.

```
var mplayer, mesb, dur, title;
OO.ready(function() {
  var lastTriggerPos;
  mplayer = OO.Player.create('ooyalaplayer', embedcode);
  mplayer.mb.subscribe(OO.EVENTS.PLAYBACK_READY, 'example', function(eventName) {
    title = mplayer.getCurrentItemTitle();
    var vData = mplayer.getItem();
    dur = parseInt(vData.time);
  });
  mplayer.mb.subscribe(OO.EVENTS.PLAYHEAD_TIME_CHANGED, 'example', function(eventName) {
    phPos = parseInt(mplayer.getPlayheadTime());
    if ((phPos == parseInt(dur * 0.25)) && phPos != lastTriggerPos) {
      lastTriggerPos = phPos;
      alert('25%');
    }
    if ((phPos == parseInt(dur * 0.50)) && phPos != lastTriggerPos) {
      lastTriggerPos = phPos;
      alert('50%');
    }
    if ((phPos == parseInt(dur * 0.75)) && phPos != lastTriggerPos) {
      lastTriggerPos = phPos;
      alert('75%');
    }
    if ((phPos == parseInt(dur * 1)) && phPos != lastTriggerPos) {
      lastTriggerPos = phPos;
      alert('100%');
    }
  });
});
```